# Threading data visualization and timers

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I am wondering what would be the best solution to a practical problem.
I am not using any threads in this small project.

It is a simple UI polling data from the serial port on a fixed timer.

Data is analyzed, filtered, and then displayed on a line chart.

Everything is working fine other than data polling "hanging" (i.e. not being executed, no error or anything) when the form is moved around on the desktop.

I don't necessarily need the chart to be updated when the form is being moved but I would at least want the timer to still tick while it's being moved (so that data polling continues).

My timer is declared as follow:

```cs
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
```

I don't have any threads defined myself, but my understanding is that timer ticks are taking place on a separate thread. Is that right?

I am handling the timer tick event like this.

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkBoxPosition.Checked)
    {
        tBoxPosition.Text = ExecuteCommand("r 1\n", tBoxPosition.Text, false, false);
        Axis.position = TryParseDouble(Axis.position, tBoxPosition.Text);
    }
}
```

I have more stuff in this event (a chart).

It's working decently, however when I drag the UI winform on the desktop it "freezes" the controls temporarily until I let go of the UI. It doesn't crash or anything, it just doesn't refresh as I am moving the window.

Not a huge deal as far as the controls are concerned, however, I just realized that the entire thread or timer were also hanging, as for the entire time where I am holding the mouse button dragging the window around nothing seems to be taking place.

Comment: Can you post some code? Otherwise, I'm afraid your question could potentially be closed...

Comment: I'd drop a BackgroundWorker control on the form and do the polling in the DoWork() handler via an infinite loop and a Sleep() call.  Once your data has been updated, use ReportProgress() to fire off the ProgressChanged() event where it'll be safe to update your line chart.

Comment: Don't do non-UI work in the UI thread.  Doing so allows your background work from preventing the UI thread from updating and allows UI updates to prevent your background work from running.

Comment: No, the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` runs on the UI thread.

Comment: See [timer differences](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/timers.html).

Comment: hmm guess that's why it's even working like this. If my timer wasn't on the UI side I would have probably gotten errors when updating controls (code only shows textboxes and checkboxes but there are also a few line charts.

Comment: You can use `async Task` see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not specify what chart package is being used, so i'm guessing the built in one from .Net.

The background worker is a good option, but it's pretty old school and takes more implementation than using `async Task`.

***Note:*** The only time it's OK to use `async void` is on top level event handlers, otherwise you should use `async Task`, see [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only)

I made it so the checkbox enables and disabled the timer, not sure what it does in your app.

Here are 2 versions of your code, v1 is where the text box gets updated after the `ExecuteCommand` has finished and v2 is where the text box gets updated within the `ExecuteCommnad` method.

Version 1: (update text on timer tick)

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Series Series1 { get; set; }
        int val = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Interval = 2000;
            chart1.Series.Clear();

            Series1 = new Series
            {
                Name = "Series1",
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
                IsVisibleInLegend = false,
                IsXValueIndexed = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            this.chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
        }

        private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tBoxPosition.Text = await ExecuteCommand("r 1\n", tBoxPosition.Text, false, false);
            tBoxPosition.Select(tBoxPosition.Text.Length - 1, 0);
            tBoxPosition.ScrollToCaret();
        }

        //not sure what you are doing her but lets say its something that takes some time..maybe a data fetch of some kind
        async Task<string> ExecuteCommand(string str, string text, bool value1, bool value2)
        {                
            StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder(text);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);

                returnString.AppendLine($"value : {val++}");
                Series1.Points.AddXY(i, (i + i + i));
            }
            return returnString.ToString();
        }

        private void chkBoxPosition_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkBoxPosition.Checked)
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            else
                timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

version 2: (update text box and chart in execute method)

```
 private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await ExecuteCommand("r 1\n", tBoxPosition.Text, false, false);

        }

        //not sure what you are doing her but lets say its something that takes some time..maybe a data fetch of some kind
        async Task ExecuteCommand(string str, string text, bool value1, bool value2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);

                Series1.Points.AddXY(i, (i + i + i));
                tBoxPosition.Text += $"value : {val++} {Environment.NewLine}";
                tBoxPosition.Select(tBoxPosition.Text.Length - 1, 0);
                tBoxPosition.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the thorough response! I will try to implement either solution today! thanks!

Comment: I elected to try using a System.Timers.Timer instead and that worked (I already had made sure my timer event didn't call any UI control and used flags and variables instead). thank you again